# IntelliJ IDEA SSH Connection fails "Worker binary deploy failed"

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, intellij-idea, ssh

I am trying to connect to my SSH Linux Server using SSH with private key in IntelliJ Idea. It runs to 100% when creating the worker binary and the exits with the following error:

Worker binary deploy failed: Worker binary deploy failed: check command log for details: File /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64.1536036234613625.tmp upload failed; stderr:

I have already tried

1. deleting the JetBrains folder
2. deleting only the remote-dev-worker
3. removing the timestamp and .tmp from tmp file (leads to ssh connection attempt skipping immediately)

This is the Log output:

```bash
2023-09-20 12:00:17,394 INFO    uname -sm
    stdout:
    Linux x86_64

2023-09-20 12:00:19,715 INFO    echo $SHELL
    stdout:
    /bin/bash

2023-09-20 12:00:20,487 INFO    uname -sm
    stdout:
    Linux x86_64

2023-09-20 12:00:23,131 INFO    echo $SHELL
    stdout:
    /bin/bash

2023-09-20 12:00:24,199 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ echo\ \$HOME
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/myrwhjoy

2023-09-20 12:00:25,942 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ echo\ \$XDG_CACHE_HOME
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-09-20 12:00:28,509 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ test\ -f\ /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-09-20 12:00:29,691 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ dirname\ /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker

2023-09-20 12:00:30,315 WARN    exit code: 129 (SIGHUP) /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ ls\ -la\ /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker

2023-09-20 12:00:30,611 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ mkdir\ -p\ /home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-09-20 12:00:32,663 WARN    exit code: null (timeout)   dd of=/home/myrwhjoy/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64.1535921040344041.tmp
    stdout:
    stdout used for binary data
```

Comment: Just facing the very same problem, using pycharm...